# Finding Image string in RTF File

Tags: regex

Hi I am trying to extract image string from the RTf file. For example consider following is my the regex:

```
\bjpgblip(.*)(\s.*)+\}
```

This expression selects upto last curly braces but i want select to the first curly brace.

```
**wmetafile\jpgblip 000ea080000700e0000a00900
000000000052000000
700100000007c
30cc74d00f0000000000000000000000
000000000000000f
7f0
260000}\par\pard\keepnLay(Material):\par\pard\b0\f1\fs20\tro
\wmetafile\jpgblip 000ea080000700e0000a00900
000000000052000000
700100000007c
30cc74d00f0000000000000000000000
000000000000000f
7f0
260000}**\par\pard\keepnLay(Material):\par\pard\b0\f1\fs20\tro
```

I am using C# Programming Language.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add a question mark `?` after your second quantifier `*` to enable **non-greedy** matching. The question mark in this case is unrelated to the quantifier `?` that means "0 or 1." Here it asks the preceding quantifier `*` to match as little as possible, rather than as much as possible. I would actually add it after both `*`s and the `+`.

```
\bjpgblip(.*?)(\s.*?)+?\}
```